# Grails list of collections assistance

Tags: grails, collections

I am doing the following in one of my GSP templates inside of a g:each :

```
events.push({title:'${ScriptHelper.escapeForJavascript(it.student.name)}\n${ScriptHelper.escapeForJavascript(it.position?.code)}',allDay:false,start:'${it.beginTimeForOverall()}',end:'${it.endTimeForOverall()}',id:'${it.id}',className:'lifeguard'});
```

I want to do the same thing but in a controller action now. I am not sure how to replicate the above into code that works in the controller:

```
currentShifts.each {
    println it
    if (it.position.description == 'Lifeguard') {
        events.add({title:ScheduleService.escapeForJavascript(it.student.name) + '\n' + ScheduleService.escapeForJavascript(it.position?.code),allDay:false,start:it.beginTimeForOverall(),end:it.endTimeForOverall(),id:it.id,className:'lifeguard'})
    } else if (it.posted) {
        events.add({title:ScheduleService.escapeForJavascript(it.student.name) + '\n' + ScheduleService.escapeForJavascript(it.position?.code),allDay:false,start:it.beginTimeForOverall(),end:it.endTimeForOverall(),id:it.id,posted:1,className:'postedEvent'})
    } else {
        events.add({title:ScheduleService.escapeForJavascript(it.student.name) + '\n' + ScheduleService.escapeForJavascript(it.position?.code),allDay:false,start:it.beginTimeForOverall(),end:it.endTimeForOverall(),id:it.id,className:it.exchangedClass()})
    }
}
```

Error received:

> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
>   C:\Users\clmoore3\Desktop\ShiftExchange2\grails-app\controllers\recschedule\SchedulesController.groovy: 125: unexpected token: temp @ line 125, column 23.
>                   events.add({title:temp,allDay:0,start:it.beginTimeForOverall(),end:it.endTimeForOverall(),id:it.id,className:'lifeguard'})

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: oh, you have to use square brackets `[...]` for map, instead of curly brackets `{...}` in groovy

Comment: One of those duh moments. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use square brackets `[...]` for map, instead of curly brackets `{...}` in groovy